# Getting the value of my amount column and pass it to my textbox. (Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Newbie here, My target is, how can I pass the value of my amount column to my textbox? I did the same logic as i pass the ID using script (below), but it's not working. I'm trying different approach but none of them is working. Hoping someone can help. Thank you in advance.

[image]

**Views:**

```
<?php 
              
                    foreach($result as $rows) {     ?>
                   <?php if($rows->status==='pending'){ ?>
                <tr>
                
                <td><?php echo $rows->userID; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rows->transID; ?></td>              
                <td><?php echo $rows->amount; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rows->currentBalance; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rows->status; ?></td>
                <td>
                
 <button data-id="<?php echo $rows->transID?>"  ustatus="approved" class="showmodal fundTable btn btn-success btn-sm text-bold user_status">
   <?php echo $rows->transID?> accept
</button>


<div id="fundModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('ewallet/statuschanged')?>">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      
          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">transID</label>
                            <input type="text" id="transID" name="transID" value="">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Amount</label>
                            <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value="<?php echo $rows->amount; ?>">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Status</label>
                            <input type="text" name="status" id="user_status" value="">
                          </div>
   
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controllers:**

```
public function statuschanged($transID = 0)
    {
        
        
        $this->ewallets->statuss($transID);
    
    }
```

**Model:**

```
function statuss($transID) {
            
            $transID = $this->input->post('transID');
            $status = $this->input->post('status');
           
            
            $data = array('status' => $status );
            $this->db->where('transID',$transID);
            $this->db->update('cash_out', $data); //Update status here
            
            return redirect('ewallet/cashout');
        }
```

**Script:**

```
<script>

$('.showmodal').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  
  $('#transID').val(this.dataset.id); // passing of ID to my textbox
  $('#fundModal').modal('show')
})


$('#fundModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#transID').val('')
  $('#ustatus').val('')
})
    </script>
```

Comment: show your complete code when you take any action.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean? I'm sorry I can't quite understand that.

Comment: can you please show your full code how your modal will appear. for example you have click on a button.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/wh9rkj << This one. Thank you for clarifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1 -**

```
<button data-amount="<?php echo $rows->amount?>" data-id="<?php echo $rows->transID?>" ustatus="approved" class="showmodal fundTable btn btn-success btn-sm text-bold user_status">
   <?php echo $rows->transID?> accept
</button>
```

**Step 2 -**

```
$('.showmodal').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  
  $('#amount').val($(this).data("amount")); // passing amount to textbox
  $('#transID').val(this.dataset.id); // passing of ID to my textbox
  $('#fundModal').modal('show')
});
```

**Step 3 -**

When model close - $('#amount').val('');